# Collatz stopping-time and Poisson distribution, and connection to other problems?

Tags: nt.number-theory, collatz-conjecture

I read many threads about Collatz here - so don't worry, this is no attempt to any proof, just asking about a curious fact:

This graph gives the stopping-time of Collatz sequences up to $n=10^8$
[image: Collatz stopping-time]
(source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CollatzStatistic100million.png ) and it's distribution looks very similar to a Poisson distribution.

Is there some known reason why the Collatz-sequence stopping time behaves like a poissonian distribution?

What are the connections to other mathematical problems: Does the Collatz-conjecture imply other conjectures, or do other conjectures imply the Collatz-conjecture?

Thank you!

Comment: By the way, that doesn't closely resemble a Poisson distribution. Poisson distributions have a variance equal to the mean, so a standard deviation equal to the square root of the mean. The mode looks about like $13^2$. Is about $95\%$ within $26$ of the mode? No, it looks like the variance is several times higher than the mean.

Comment: Did you mean "threads" or was it really "threats"? In both cases, however, the question remains the same :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As to the observed distribution of total stopping times for integers $n \leq 10^8$,
I think heuristically this can be explained quite well by the obvious stochastic model
(multiply $n$ by $3/2$ or $1/2$, each with probability $1/2$, repeat this
until the number gets $\leq 1$ and count the number of steps this takes).
For literature on such stochastic considerations, see Lagarias'
annotated bibliography on the conjecture (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309224).
Proving anything is of course *quite* a different task!

The Collatz conjecture can be formulated in quite a number of equivalent
ways, see also Lagarias' bibliography. Though so far the conjecture is *by far*
not as well-embedded into known parts of mathematics as for example the Riemann
Hypothesis. Namely I am not aware of, say, important 'theorems' which are
proved up to the Collatz conjecture. Nevertheless, I think the fact that an
easy-to-state question like the Collatz conjecture seems so intractable
suggests that certain important things are not understood so far.
Hence I don't think the conjecture will seem as isolated as now for all
future -- but of course this is my personal view.

Comment: Thank you for the answere. Indeed your explanation with the simple statistical model gives the same result for big n (and interesting deviations for smaller n - just tested it with mathematica). Very interesting that it follows the rules of random events for big numbers - did not expect.

Comment: So if you use all the $2$-adic integers, with its Haar measure, then it would have a nice distribution.  But corresponding properties upon restricting to the rational integers (a set of probability zero) are not simple to prove, or even (so far) possible to prove.